# How to identify a dynamically changing html id using QTP/UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

There is a text field on the page that I would like QTP to enter amount for me. The HTML ID of the field has a dynamic name gh44jer4u.Amount but ends with a word amount. How can I refer to that? Can I use Contains or Ends with inside html id?

Something like this:

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebEdit("html id:=.Amount").Set "348934"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using descriptive programming UFT uses regular expressions. So the `.` you're using is not the literal string `"."`, rather it means *any single character*.

The description needs to fit the entire string so you need something like this.

```
.*\.Amount
```

Which according to [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/) means:

> /.*.Amount/
>   `.*` matches any character (except newline)
>   Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>   `\.` matches the character `.` literally
>   `Amount` matches the characters `Amount` literally (case sensitive)

So the full line should be:

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebEdit("html id:=.*\.Amount").Set "348934"
```